pyplot.contour() with specific levels returns incomplete figure
I'm trying to plot a figure of composite of extreme warming cases from CESM2 large ensemble climate data. I tried the following codes and it returned an incomplete world map.
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))
level = [-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40,50,60] 
ax.contour(lon, lat, z3_composite_mean - z3_djf_mean, levels=level,colors='k',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 


But the codes below gave complete map!
level = np.arange(-60,60.1,10)  
ax.contour(lon, lat, z3_composite_mean - z3_djf_mean, levels=level, colors='k',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())


Or is it related to plotting coastlines with cartopy packages?
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE) 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, color='lightgrey')

Hope to figure out this confusing result, thanks!
I tried the contourf function, and the shading looks normal. Only contour plot suffers problem :(

I am surprised by this.  Most bug reports say that contour is OK but contourf has a problem!  I am curious what versions of Matplotlib and Cartopy you are using.

matplotlib: 3.3.4, cartopy: 0.19.0.post1. Is it the problem of version? They're not the latest since I also install pyngl package in current environment, which requires certain version to prevent from compatibility issues.

Thanks for replying!  It's possible the problem would go away with newer versions.  There has been a lot of change in Matplotlib for how contour works since v3.3.4.  It looks like you have a workaround for the old version anyway.

The solution is to use levels, including level=0, then turn it transparent:
for i, collection in enumerate(contour.collections): 
    if level[i] == 0: 
       collection.set_alpha(0) 
    else: 
       collection.set_alpha(1)

